# Chart.js - setting tooltip z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/gmannib/j2mwpj43/7/

^ See the sample fiddle above. Notice how the tooltips for the piechart go underneath the "earth" icon I have in the middle there? Is there a way to set the z-index property of the tooltips to be above the earth icon?  I thought this would work?

```
race.tooltip.style.zIndex = "5";
```

I'm still learning...thank you for your kind help!

Comment: visit this for more info:http://www.rgraph.net/docs/using-tooltips-in-your-charts.html

Comment: @suchit i dont think that rgraph's docs apply to chartjs.. Instead look it up [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just give higher `z-index` value to your canvas and you are done. See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/j2mwpj43/10/)**.

CSS Code

```
canvas#race{position:relative; z-index:1;}
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. Just for my education: why is it canvas#race instead of just #race?  I think I tried this with just #race and it actually didn't work?  Why?

Comment: Just FYI for those stopping by, "race" is what he named his canvas.  So it's <canvas id="race" ... >

Comment: that is changing the `z-index` of the canvas instead of the tooltips, isn't it?